# Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using remote hadoop and hbase on linux machine for connection but it is expecting HADOOP_HOME from my local machine while getting data through hbase client

```
HTable hTable = new HTable(conf, "user");
```

on this line .
used 
hbase-client:0.98.6-cdh5.3.0
and hadoop-client:2.5.0-cdh5.3.0 in gradle file

making local hadoop and pasting winutils into it does not help as is mentioned in 
[Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)
What I have done wrong .

Comment: duplicated by (but with an answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136092/hadoophbase-cluster-on-windows-winutils-not-found